# Vue + Typescript - Import errors with class based decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to set up Vue 3 with TypeScript and class-based components. However, I keep getting on error on importing the `Component` decorator the `Vue` constructor:

> ```
> This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof
> import("/Users/*folder*/node_modules/vue-class-component/dist/vue-class-component")'
> has no call signatures. Vetur(2349)
> ```

*mycode.vue:*

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component // 1st Error '@Component'
export default class ProdItem extends Vue { // 2nd error 'Vue'
  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be trying to use the example from the official `vue-class-component` docs, but that's currently for the 7x version, which can only be used with Vue 2.

Vue 3 requires `vue-class-component` [8x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-class-component/v/8.0.0-beta.4), which is not yet documented, but you can refer to [`vue-class-component` Issue #406](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406) that describes the changes. The notices relevant to your question:

> - `@Component` will be renamed to `@Options`.
> - `@Options` is optional if you don't declare any options with it.
> - `Vue` constructor is provided from `vue-class-component` package.

Since your component has no options, you could just omit the `@Options` decorator from your component:

```js
// BEFORE:
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
@Component
class {}

// AFTER:
/* no options used, so no @Options decorator needed */
class {}
```

Also, Vue 3 no longer exports the Vue constructor, but `vue-class-component` does, so your component would have to extend that instead:

```js
// BEFORE:
import Vue from 'vue'

// AFTER:
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component'
```

For reference, you can use [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)  to generate a *Vue 3 + TypeScript* project to play with a working example that uses the latest `vue-class-component` as described above.

Answer (score 0):

With a decorator, you don't need `({})`.
Try

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component  // 1st Error '@Component'
export default class ProdItem extends Vue { // 2nd error 'Vue'
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I left that there by accident. I just edited the post. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/416) and this [one](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406) you could do :

```
<script lang="ts">

import {vue} from 'vue-class-component'


export default class ProdItem extends Vue { 
  
}
</script>
```