# Vue 3 Composition API - Property returned by setup() "accessed during render but is not defined on instance."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm toying around with Vue 3's Composition API creating a small in-app message console, and I don't get where is the error in my code.
Rendering this component, `state` is accessed during render (in the loop) but I think I correctly defined it in the object returned by `setup()`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="message" v-for="message in state.messages" v-bind:key="message.id">{{message.text}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" >
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import { consoleStore } from "@/store/ConsoleStore"

@Options({})
export default class Console extends Vue {
  setup() {
      console.log("setup entered")
      consoleStore.record("This is a test.")
      let state = consoleStore.getState()
      return {
        state
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

What's more, the `console.log("setup entered")` line does not output anything to the dev console. As if the setup block is never entered.
For `consoleStore` I'm implementing the simple Vue 3 store class proposed in [this article](https://medium.com/@mario.brendel1990/vue-3-the-new-store-a7569d4a546f), so it should be a `readonly(reactive(stuff))`:

```js
import { reactive, readonly } from 'vue';

export abstract class AbstractStore<T extends Object> {
    protected state: T;

    constructor() {
        let data = this.data();
        this.setup(data);
        this.state = reactive(data) as T;
    }

    protected abstract data(): T

    protected setup(data: T): void { }

    public getState(): T {
        return readonly(this.state) as T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing to import `setup` inside the class component :

```js
import { Options, Vue,setup  } from 'vue-class-component';
import { consoleStore } from "@/store/ConsoleStore"

function useState () {
 console.log("setup entered")
      consoleStore.record("This is a test.")
      let state = consoleStore.getState()
      return {
        state
      }
}
@Options({})
export default class Console extends Vue {
 state= setup(() =>useState()) 
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, and I have no idea why. Where is this documented?

Comment: please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264608/8172857) you will find two links that detail these features