# What is the meaning of @Options in Vue 3 with class-component?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a project using Vue 3 with `class-component` and `typescript`, and I found syntax `@Option` in the App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  name: "App"
})
export default class extends Vue {}
</script>
```

What is the meaning of `@Options`? Does it have a difference with the `@Component`?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262860/vue-typescript-import-errors-with-class-based-decorators

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue + Typescript - Import errors with class based decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262860/vue-typescript-import-errors-with-class-based-decorators)

Answer (score 1):

meaning @Option use in vue 3 because, your project use terpati/libary vue-class-component. it detail about libary vue-class-component can you look in url below:
https://class-component.vuejs.org/.
documentation use @Component dont't use @Option. because documentation for vue2. when use vue 3 @Component replace using @Options

Comment: find the [changelog](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406)

Answer (score -2):

While Vue Class API solves a lot of problem, it comes with a number of problems and it's not really recommended. See Evan You, creator of Vue take on this
https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17#issuecomment-494242121

Comment: While this information is useful and correct it's more of a comment than an answer to the question at hand.